# Cannot read property '_defaults' of undefined Jquery Mobile datepicker

Tags: jquery-mobile, datepicker

I am trying to implement the Jquery Mobile datepicker wrapper http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/datepicker/ but it is giving me errors from the datepicker.js file Cannot read property '_defaults' of undefined . I dont think it is recognising the js file at all.

I have referenced it in the index.html in the head

```
<script src="js/jquery.mobile.datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.datepicker.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.datepicker.theme.css" />
```

then called it as below

```
<input type="text" id="date-input" data-inline="true" data-role="date">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import jquery-ui as well.